# $anchorScroll point to a link but doesn't access it

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to redirect to some elements of my DOM in the same page.
I used the following code,
JS:

```
 $scope.scrollTo = function (id) {
        $location.hash(id);
        $anchorScroll();
    };
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="chartdiv15" class="chartdiv"></div>
    <div id="chartdata15" class="chartdata"></div>
</div>
```

and :

```
     <md-input-container>
        <label>Menu</label>
        <md-select ng-model="menu">
          .....
          <md-option ng-click="scrollTo('chartdiv15')">click</md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
```

So  this process enable me to point to the link (http://localhost:3000/#/graphics#chartdiv15) 
[image]

It get to the element and within a second it redirect to the top of the page as if I didn't nothing ...
Someone can help me to solve this weired problem?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not using $location.hash(id); but only $anchorScroll(id);

According to the documentation of [$anchorscroll](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) :

> When called, it scrolls to the element related to the specified hash or (if omitted) to the current value of $location.hash(), according to the rules specified in the HTML5 spec.

In my project, I use only  $anchorScroll(id), it works great but of course the URL is not updated.

If you want the URL updated as well maybe you should use:

```
    $location.hash(id);
    $anchorScroll();   // <- no id here
```

Sorry for not answering your question directly but I don't think we can help you with just the data provided, if you add a plunker reproducing the issue, it would be easier to advise.

Comment: I edited the question I didn't had id in $anchorScroll and I still have the same problem

Comment: And just for testing purposes, if you just use $anchorScroll(id) and don't use  $location.hash(id) at all, do you have the expected behaviour (except URL update) ?